# Ajax Select, getting data out of database with select

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

How do I get the value out of an database using the following: A user selects id (i.e 1) within a `<select>` function then the data is displayed in a `<p>` tag
I have the following and I am able to change the text with the `<p>` but I can't get the data out of the database for some reason

**Select Code**

```
<p id="dbinfo" >Data comes here</p>


<select id='slct'>
    <option value='empty'>select a number</option>
    <option value='1'> 1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
</select>

<script>     
    document.getElementById("slct").onfocus = function()
    {
        alert(document.getElementById('slct').value);

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var text = "";
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
                var dbText = xmlhttp.responseText;
                var obj = JSON.parse(); 
                var text;
                var i;
                for(i =0; i < obj.records.length; i++)
                {
                    text += "<option value='" +obj.records[i].id+ "'>" + obj.records[i].id + "</option>";
                }
                document.getElementById('dbinfo').innerHTML = dbText;

            }            
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost/somemaps/data.php", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send();

        document.getElementById("slct").onchange = function(){
            var id = this.children[this.selectedIndex].value;
            document.getElementById("dbinfo").innerHTML = "text has changed: " +id;

            xmlhttp1 = xmlhttpRequest(); 
            xmlhttp.send("id="+id);         
        }
    }


</script>
```

**Data Code**

```
<?php
    //Haal de gegevens uit de database en echo ze naar dit scherm.
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $databasename = "blok-1-am1a";

    if(isset($_POST['id']))
    {
        $extra = "WHERE ".$id. " = ".$_POST['id'];
    }
    else
    {
        $extra = "";
    }

    try
    {
        $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=".$servername.";dbname=".$databasename, $username, $password);
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT `id`, `firstname`, FROM `db-name` ".$extra);


        $statement->execute();

        $result = $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $data = "";
        foreach($statement->fetchAll() as $key => $value)
        {
            $data .= $value['id']." | ".$value['firstname'];
        }

    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Dit is een PDO foutmelding, de volgende fout heeft plaatsgevonden : ".$e->getMessage();


    }

    echo $data;


?>
```

I was thinking that I should add a value to return? but this does not seem to work so what could be the problem? Any tips/anwsers are welcome (:

*Edit*

After cliffs response and changing my code to his this is the result:

[image: Page as is]

And after selecting this happens:

[image: After select]

So as said all the data from the database just shows instead of the selected id

Comment: Hi @RDAxRoadkill, does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938559/ajax-select-getting-data-out-of-database-with-select/30944207#30944207) answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three problems I've found in your code:

- There is a typo on line ***9*** of the **`PHP`** code you posted:
  I think that `$extra ="WHERE ".$id=$_POST['id'];` should be `$extra ="WHERE ".$id."=".$_POST['Id'];` note the equal sign `=` enclosed in double quotes.
- On line ***32*** still in the **`PHP`** code `$data .= $value['id']." | ".$value['firstname']";` remove the last double quote before the semicolon like so:
  `$data .= $value['id']." | ".$value['firstname'];`
- The event you are looking for to make an `AJAX` call when user selects id within a `<select>` is the `onchange`, in **jQuery [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/)**.
  So listen on its event on line ***14*** of your **`JS`** code too: instead of `onfocus` use `onchange` like so `document.getElementById("slct").onchange = function()`

Then, since you tagged your post with [**`jQuery`**](https://jquery.com/), you can use the [`AJAX` methods of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) which is faster and easier to use.

I would suggest the [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method:

```
$("#slct").change(function() {
    var idVar = $(this).val(); // The jQuery version of this.children[this.selectedIndex].value
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost/somemaps/data.php",
        type:"post",
        data: {id: idVar},
        async:true,
        success: function(data) {
            //  Code to be executed if the request succeeds eg:
            $("#dbinfo").html(data);
            //  The data variable contains the content returned from the server
            },
        error: function() {
            //  Code to be executed if the request fails
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi @Cliff, thank you for your response. Although there are some typos so that would be errors(thank you for finding them) changing the script to the jquery function doe give some result but not much. I used your code (just copy + pasted it) but that just drops my database to the page so is there anything I should add?

Comment: I'm sorry @RDAxRoadkill, but I do not understand very well what is the problem now. What do you mean for ***"that just drops my database to the page"*** ? Can you edit your question to show the result?
And if you've copied my code exactly as it is, remember to change the url and the data.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear @cliff, I mean that when I press the button all the stored data in the database is displayed, instead of id 1 for exampl. I changed both the url and data, and i'll edit my question

Comment: Ok thank you @RDAxRoadkill, it seems that you're not giving the right data to the `PHP` script, resulting in assignment of an empty string to the `$extra` variable _(the first `if() ... else` of your `PHP` script)_. I want to point out that the **jQuery's AJAX** `data` parameter must be formatted as an object like so: `{number: 4, string: "hello", variable: variableName}` so if in the `PHP` code you expect `$_POST["id"]` you have to write this `{id: this.children[this.selectedIndex].value}` Are you doing this?

Comment: I've updated my answer, now it should work as expected. The **jQuery** version of `this.children[this.selectedIndex].value` is `$(this).val()`

Comment: This should all be added into my input script right? Is there anything I should change in my data file, I've tried your anwser but yet I am still getting the same result as before: the entire database is displayed on the page.

Comment: Yes, you should replace your entire `JS` code with my code keeping the code inside the `if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)` and placing it in the `success: function() { // Your code}` of the code I posted. For the *data* file: Can you update the code in your question? (only update writing *"**Data code** (updated)"*) - There are two possibilities: **1-** In the `JS` code you posted you do two ajax calls, including one with no parameters, resulting in the `SELECT` with no clauses **2-** the **9th** line of your `PHP` code is still as you wrote (check *1st* point of my answer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81604/discussion-between-cliff-burton-and-rdaxroadkill).

Answer (score 0):

```
$sth = $connection->prepare("SELECT `id`, `firstname`, FROM `db-name` WHERE ".((isset($_POST['id'])) ? "`id`" : ":id")." = :id");
$sth->execute(array(":id" => (isset($_POST["id"])) ? $_POST["id"] : 0));
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this does not work for me, did you change anything else?